# Magento redirecting to the installation page

Tags: magento-1.9, database, redirect, installation, redirect-url

I  made a backup of the website and after some time  Whenever  I try to view the site through my browser it redirects to the magento install page. It was working fine previously  and suddenly this happen. 
I checked the solution regarding to it on stack exchange  and found that i dont have **app** **directory** in root folder to modify any file . Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: The chief cause of this is a missing or misnamed local.xml file in app/etc/ - this file is responsible for database connection details and cache settings.
or local.xml file is missing

Comment: otherwise local.xml files any other configure file  example ( local.backup.xml)

Comment: @RamaChandran i have checked that server through FTP but there is no app folder

Comment: That is the problem. Please check app folder moved to any other folder.

Comment: @RamaChandran i have found that app folder was in other directory so i should just place it where it was ?

Comment: just place rootdirectory/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your app folder moved to any other folder. please check move to root directory.